# Jupyter widgets: disable a button if input is empty else enable?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

```py
widgets.VBox([
    widgets.Text(value=""),
    widgets.Button(
        description="Click",
        disabled=# ???,
    )
]
)
```

How could I make the button disable based on the input value?

Disable when input is `''`, else make the button enabled?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. If anyone is interested:

```py
input = widgets.Text(value="")

def on_click(b):
    if input.value:
        # ...


button = widgets.Button(
    description="Click",
    disabled=True,
)
button.on_click(on_click)

# disable button if input is empty
def value_changed(change):
    button.disabled = not bool(change.new)


input.observe(value_changed, "value")
```